# Как лучше создать такую конструкцию изображений?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Необходимо построить 3 изображения подобным образом. С помощью чего лучше это сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: с помощью CSS()

Comment: Спасибо, я понимаю. Более подробную информацию можете дать? Как сверстать это?

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если я правильно понял, о чём вы

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.block__inner {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.block__row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.block__row:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: -20px;
  width: calc(100% + 40px);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__inner">
    <div class="block__row">
      <div class="block__image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="alt">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block__row">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="alt">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="alt">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```